# Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket

I am working on a react application with typescript but I ran into an error with AxiosResquestHeader which keeps getting type not assignable. I'd wanted to get the current token for the signed-in user from localStorage.
this is my AuthHeaders.ts

```
export default function authHeader(): AxiosRequestHeaders {
  type userToken = {
  accessToken: string;
};
  const localstorageUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
  if (!localstorageUser) {
    return {};
  }
  const user = JSON.parse(localstorageUser);
  if (user && user.token) {
    return { Authorization: `Token ${user.token}` };
  }
  return {};

}
```

and this gets called from AuthContext.ts as follows

```
export const AuthContextProvider: React.FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [user, setUser] = useState(() => AuthService.getCurrentUser());

  async function login(email: string, password: string) {
    const data = await AuthService.login(email, password);
    setUser(data);
    return data;
  }

  function logout() {
    AuthService.logout();
    setUser(null);
    navigate("/login");
  }

  // axios instance for making requests
  const authAxios = axios.create();

  // request interceptor for adding token
  authAxios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // add token to request headers
   ** config.headers = authHeader();**
    return config;
  });
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
ERROR in src/services/AuthHeaders.ts:14:5

TS2322: Type '{ Authorization: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
  Type '{ Authorization: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosHeaders': set, get, has, delete, and 23 more.
    12 |   const user = JSON.parse(localstorageUser);
    13 |   if (user && user.token) {
  > 14 |     return { Authorization: `Token ${user.token}` };
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    15 |     // throw new Error('User Token Found');
    16 |   }
    17 |   // return {};


ERROR in src/services/AuthHeaders.ts:14:5

TS2322: Type '{ Authorization: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AxiosRequestHeaders'.
  Type '{ Authorization: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'AxiosHeaders': set, get, has, delete, and 23 more.
    12 |   const user = JSON.parse(localstorageUser);
    13 |   if (user && user.token) {
  > 14 |     return { Authorization: `Token ${user.token}` };
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    15 |     // throw new Error('User Token Found');
    16 |   }
    17 |   // return {};
```

when I comment out the return methods in AuthHeaders.ts and replace them with `throw new Error()` the program seems to compile without any issues but of course, the logic is incorrect.

I am a bit new to typescript and react concepts but I am sure that this could be with **typescript return types**. Anyways I really need your help. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You might want to use `RawAxiosRequestHeaders` instead of `AxiosRequestHeaders`.

`AxiosRequestHeaders` is a class inherited from `AxiosHeaders` which cannot be instantiated just from an object (`{}`).

`RawAxiosRequestHeaders` on the other hand is just an interface and probably fit for what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are just returning an object that contains the authorization token. For that, the return type of `authHeader` need not necessarily be `AxiosRequestHeaders`

You can use this in the function's return type.

```
type userToken = {
  accessToken: string;
};

export default function authHeader(): {Authorization: string} | {} {
  const localstorageUser = localStorage.getItem("user");
  const user = JSON.parse(localstorageUser);
  if (user && user.token) {
    return { Authorization: `Token ${user.token}` };
  }
  return {};
}
```